# Format pandas dataframe index date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe that I got from the below code, but I am unable to convert the `date` index to dd/mm/yyyy

```
df= pandas.read_html(base_url, header=0, index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)[0]
df.index = pandas.to_datetime(df.index, dayfirst=True)
```

This is the result

```
            Col1  Col2   
Date                                          
2017-02-10  val1  val1  
2017-02-09  val2  val2  
2017-02-08  val3  val3  
2017-02-07  val4  val4
```

I have tired a couple of other different variations that I searched for on stackoverflow, but i'm not able to find a combination that works.

it still prints out the `date` as `yyyy-mm-dd`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If need `DatetimeIndex` then is is problem, because `yyyy-mm-dd` is default display format of `dates` in `pandas`.

If need `string` index by [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
df.index = df.index.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
print (df)
            Col1  Col2
10/02/2017  val1  val1
09/02/2017  val2  val2
08/02/2017  val3  val3
07/02/2017  val4  val4

print (type(df.index[0]))
<class 'str'>
```

Unfortunately this does not work - [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#available-options):

```
with pd.option_context('display.date_dayfirst', True):
    print (df)

            Col1  Col2
Date                  
2017-02-10  val1  val1
2017-02-09  val2  val2
2017-02-08  val3  val3
2017-02-07  val4  val4
```