# convert index format date

Tags: pandas, date, format, series

I have a data Series in which the index is a list of dates

```
IN: [318]: weightedflows
Out[318]:

2015-01-31 00:00:00                0
2015-02-28 00:00:00                0
2015-02-28 00:00:00.1              0
2015-02-28 00:00:00.2              0
2015-03-31 00:00:00                0
2015-03-31 00:00:00.1              0
2015-03-31 00:00:00.2    1.77419e+07
2015-03-31 00:00:00.3     1.6129e+07
2015-03-31 00:00:00.4              0
```

What i'd like to do is reformat the values in the index of this Series so that it reads as `2/28/2015` or `3/31/2015`.  How do I reformat the index of this Series?  Not sure how datetime can be applied here?

I tried weightedflows.index.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") but get 'Index' object has no attribute 'strftime'.  If it helps, my data type is pandas.core.indexes.base.Index

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format pandas dataframe index date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42185328/format-pandas-dataframe-index-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If index consists of datetime objects, then: `series.index = series.index.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')`

If not, you may have to go out of your way to convert them to datetime objects, so you can revert back to strings: `series.index = pd.to_datetime(series.index).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')`